# Search Engine Optimization (SEO) & Friendly URLs using ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

please tell me best to achieve Search Engine Optimization (SEO) & Friendly URLs using ASP.Net

Answer (score 1):

As far as SEO is concerned take a look at this guide from Google: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35291&topic=15260

It won't tell you exactly how to do it in ASP.NET but it will give advice on how to improve your websites SEO in general.  Then once you decide a task to improve your SEO, you can focus on how to achieve that specific item in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

I have some ideas for you;

```
1- avoid using table. use div instead.
2- write the title of the page then use general description of the page;
  for instance; Apples , Goldville Co. 
3- keep your keywords up to five for each page. use a sentence for the description which only describes the current page.
4- for asp.net I recommend intelligencia component which is free. or if you use asp.net mvc, friendly url comes default.
5- keep linking among pages. like wikipedia does.
```

and never forget; content is the king!

good luck
bk